# Outlook macro only saved one attached file and stops

Tags: vba, outlook

I compiled macro that worked well, but then I further "improved" it and for some reason it stops after first successful loop. Macro saves attachments from emails to folder on NAS. The second run it stops on SaveAsFile line. Thank you for any comments.

```
    Public Sub SaveAttsToNAS(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment ' A document or link to a document contained in an Outlook item.
    Dim sSaveFolder As String
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim regDate As Date
    Dim strDate As String
    Dim objFSO, strFolder

    Dim strAtmtName(1)      As String       ' strAtmtName(0): to save the name; strAtmtName(1): to save the file extension. They are separated by dot of an attachment file name.
    Dim intDotPosition      As Integer      ' The dot position in an attachment name.
    Dim strAtmtFullName     As String       ' The full name of an attachment.

    sSaveFolder = "P:\"
    regDate = MItem.ReceivedTime
    strDate = Format(regDate, "yyyymmdd")
    sPath = sSaveFolder & strDate

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If Not objFSO.FolderExists(sPath) Then
       objFSO.CreateFolder (sPath)
    End If

    For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
        ' Get the full name of the current attachment.
      strAtmtFullName = oAttachment.FileName
      intDotPosition = InStrRev(strAtmtFullName, ".")
        ' Get the file extension.
      strAtmtName(1) = Right$(strAtmtFullName, Len(strAtmtFullName) - intDotPosition)
        ' Exclude Gifs and save the current attachment.
      If strAtmtName(1) <> "gif" Then
        oAttachment.SaveAsFile sPath  & "\" & strAtmtFullName
      End If

    Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: Edit the question to include the text of the error message and the types of attachments.

Comment: I think `If LCase(Right$(strAtmtFullName, 3)) <> "gif" Then` would be easier than the code necessary to create `StrAtmtName(1)`.

Comment: You have one output folder per day.  If two attachments sent on the same day had the same name, this code would fail.

Comment: Thank you for your comments!

Comment: Thank you for your comments!
Yesterday, during debugging process it just stopped after one successful file saved without any error. Flow was like, first found GIF, which was skipped, then first PDF successfully saved, and finish. No attempt to save another file and there were three PDF files attached all with different name.
Now, the clear code you can see above returns error message: "Run-time error -2147024894 (80070002)
"Cannot save the attachment. Cannot find this file. Verify the path and file name are correct"

Comment: Folder exists because it is created by the macro. File also exists. As for files, they are always different files every day. That is why I create folder on daily basis. Original code that I found on internet put all files into one folder from multiple mails and worked perfect, but it was a mess of many files. So, I added the subfolder by received date of mail and also skipping the GIF that are usually just decoration in the mail body.

Comment: Latest update, it again runs and finished without any error after only one file saved. I am lost here.. spent all day figuring out what makes is prevent to process another file but with no success..

Comment: So, after 2 days of testing, I have this theory. The problem is in saveasfile trying to save on network disk (NAS). Apparently, the lag of the NAS is too long and function ends in error. Sometimes it fails immediately when testing existence of the folder (results in error 80070002), sometimes crashes later during verification of written file. That happens without any error message just by terminating the script and the result is then only first attachment saved. Experimentally confirmed by changing destination folder to local disk and back to NAS using several different scripts. Any ideas???

Answer (score 0):

I the error is inconsistent, you may be able to wait it out.

```
Public Sub SaveAttsToNAS(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)

....

Dim i As Long
Dim numTries As Long

....

    ' Exclude Gifs and save the current attachment.
    If strAtmtName(1) <> "gif" Then

        i = 0
        numTries = 100

retryNAS:
        On Error GoTo slowNAS
        oAttachment.SaveAsFile sPath & "\" & strAtmtFullName
        Debug.Print "Attachment path and name: " & sPath & "\" & strAtmtFullName
        On Error GoTo 0

    End If

Next

Exiting:
Exit Sub

slowNAS:

i = i + 1
Debug.Print i & " Err.number: " & Err.number & " - Err.Description: " & Err.Description

If i >= numTries Then

    If MsgBox("Tried " & numTries & " times. Again?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        i = 0
        Resume retryNAS
    Else
        Resume Exiting
    End If

Else
    Resume retryNAS
End If

End Sub
```